# What is a person if they are described as a "wet hen"?

Tags: phrases, british-english, books

In Terry Pratchett's *Discworld* books (*Witches Abroad* in particular), the character Magrat Garlick is often called a "wet hen" by at least one of her witch colleagues.

Web searches only yielded the phrase [[to be] "mad as a wet hen"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mad%20as%20a%20wet%20hen). From the description there I think it could mean that she is looking for her "nest", meaning she is trying to get a man, but I am far from certain.

From context in the books I am pretty sure that it does *not* mean she is mad. She does actually seem quite sane, for a Discworld character anyway.

Here are some quotes for context:

> Even Magrat had one [a witch hat], although she hardly ever wore it on account of being a wet hen.
>
> "That's 'cos you're a wet hen, Magrat Garlick," said Granny.

Comment: "Mad" usually means *insane* in British English - as you've interpreted it - but in American English it almost always means *angry*.  ["Mad as a wet hen"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mad+as+a+wet+hen) does not mean "crazy", it means "extremely angry" (it's probably a euphemism for "mad as hell").  However, Pratchett is using **wet hen** in a completely different context (see @PapaCharlie9's answer); the American equivalent of this phrase might be [wet blanket](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wet_blanket).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In context, I took the phrase to mean dull, drab, a party-pooper.

Then I found this [citation](http://www.lspace.org/books/apf/witches-abroad.html):

> - [p. 159/139] "'That's 'cos you're a wet hen, Magrat Garlick,' said Granny."
>
> When questioned about the phrase, Terry explained: "Perfectly good
>   British slang. A 'wet hen' is bedraggled, sad and useless. Probably
>   not as useless as a big girl's blouse, though, and better off than a
>   lame duck."

Comment: So much like a wet blanket, then.

Comment: Maggie Thatcher described the only Conservative MP to join the SDP as 'as wet as a Dogger Bank trawler'. Not a common insult, but the meaning is tolerably clear.

Comment: I think that answer pretty much covers it, thanks!

Comment: +1, in Dostoevsky’s The Idiot, translated by Richard Pevear, at the start of Part 3 they describe being a “wet hen” synonymous with the word “placid” but in a pejorative sense

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it would be used with the same meaning here... But in french a 'wet hen' (poule mouillée) is common expression for a wuss or a weakling...

Answer (score 2):

My father used to affectionately refer to me as “silly as a wet hen” as a child. It was usually said when I was in a capricious mood. His mother’s family and ancestors were from Yorkshire in England - perhaps it was a common expression there

Answer (score 0):

In the film Waterloo (1970), the Duke of Wellington (Christopher Plumber) when pressed by one of his officers to address a new threat, says the following:

> I do not care to run around like a wet hen. There'll be plenty of time, sir. Plenty of time.

Also in the book The Secret War (M.F.W. Curran)- Page 314

> I for one will not run around like a wet hen waiting to be caught.

The implied meaning (for me) is someone who runs around in a panic, not really knowing what they are doing. I think it is similar to the expression *headless chicken*.

Answer (score 0):

All I know is all of my female West Texas relatives, including my mom , her sister, her mother and all my Aunts used the expression "madder than a wet hen" to mean furiously angry. 
Expressed by the Webb women, who tended to sound like a bunch of hens when they got together, gabbing away, the expression was always extremely evocative.My Great Aunt Marie even cackled like a chicken. I could easily visualize exactly what a wet hen looked like. Not the chicken kind, though, a wet hen is an angry woman.